# Thread safe file copy

Tags: c, multithreading, file, unix, pthreads

I'm trying to write a program that backs up multiple files to a folder called .backups. It creates one thread for each file or subdirectory, and that thread is responsible for the copy operation. However it's not working correctly. Sometimes files are never copied, sometimes they are but there are 0 bytes, and sometimes it works correctly. It seems completely random and I have no idea what's causing it. Can anyone help me figure it out?

```
// Copies the file from source to destination and returns number of bytes written
ssize_t copy_file(char* from, char *to)
{
    const int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    ssize_t n;
    ssize_t written = 0;
    FILE* file_from = fopen(from, "r");
    FILE* file_to = fopen(to, "w");

    if (file_from == NULL || file_to == NULL)
        return -1;

    while ((n = fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, file_from)) > 0) {
        if (fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), n, file_to) != n)
            return -1;
        written += n;
    }
    return written;
}


// Thread responsible for handling the backup of a single file or subdirectory
void* backup_thread(void* arg)
{
    struct backup_info* info = (struct backup_info*) arg;
    ssize_t written;

    written = copy_file(info->file, info->destination);

    int rc = pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    if (rc != 0)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    free(info);
    return NULL;
}
```

EDIT: Also, this is how I am creating each of the threads.

```
 struct backup_info* info = malloc(sizeof(struct backup_info));


 if ((rc = pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, backup_thread, info)) != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_create() failed (%d): %s", rc, strerror(rc));
```

Comment: As long as you're not using global variables, your functions should be reentrant.  How about using a mutex?

Comment: Where would I add this mutex in?

Comment: Beginning and end of `copy_file`.

Comment: Looks like `fwrite` is not atomic.

Comment: How about read() and write() ?

Comment: It's probably best to assume not.

Answer (score 2):

How does the main thread exit?

If it just returns from `main()`, then that is the same as calling `exit()`, and will result in all the other threads being unceremoniously killed in the middle of whatever they happen to be doing.

If instead you call `pthread_exit()` explicitly in `main()`, then the detached threads will be allowed to finish before the process exits.

Note also that the `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` in `backup_thread()` has the same problem - if that error case fires, it will tear down the entire process immediately.  `pthread_exit()` may be better used here as well.

Answer (score 0):

I spotted something wrong that may be causing your problem.  You never call `fclose()` on any of your files.  That will eventually lead to using up all of your file descriptors (which are shared among your threads).  I don't know if that is the only thing wrong, but you should make the fix and see what happens.

Comment: @DCJ How many threads are you creating?  Also, are any of your `fopen`, `fread` or `fwrite` calls returning an error?  You should try printing something if you get an error to help track down what is going wrong.